# Grouping tags by processes

Tags: grouping, azure-data-explorer

I have a variable that is being collected over time, during a process. The process starts when the STATUS is equal to 2 and ends when the STATUS is equal to 11. What I need to develop in kusto an ID column, which groups the tag values each time the process runs. Can you help me with this?

[image]

Comment: it may help if you provide the expected output for that input, alongside an explanation of *what kind* of 'grouping' you wish to perform (e.g. do you want the average of `Value`? the list of `Value`s? etc.)

Comment: Hello Yoni, maybe I haven't explained myself correctly: the important thing for me is to create an ID for each time interval that the process runs and to be able (in power bi for example) to select the values of Tag1 linked to that ID. It may be that some calculation will be made later, but not at the moment. The process is not continuous, it starts (STATUS = 2), middle (several other values) and end (STATUS = 11) and runs several times a day. I tried to use Ident = row_number in several ways, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

below is one option to generate the `Id` column, using `row_cumsum()`, and based on the input dataset you've provided. It may give you a direction to implement your full solution

```
datatable(timestamp:datetime, tag:string, value:double, status:int)
[
    datetime(2020-07-04 12:00), 'Tag1', 15.2391, 2,
    datetime(2020-07-04 12:02), 'Tag1', 13.452, 2,
    datetime(2020-07-04 12:04), 'Tag1', 17.239, 4,
    datetime(2020-07-04 12:15), 'Tag1', 21.891, 4,
    datetime(2020-07-04 12:17), 'Tag1', 18.9, 11,
    datetime(2020-07-04 12:30), 'Tag1', 12, 2,
    datetime(2020-07-04 12:32), 'Tag1', 15, 2,
    datetime(2020-07-04 12:33), 'Tag1', 9, 2,
    datetime(2020-07-04 12:45), 'Tag1', 17.5, 4,
    datetime(2020-07-04 12:48), 'Tag1', 42, 11,
    datetime(2020-07-04 13:12), 'Tag1', 22, 2,
    datetime(2020-07-04 13:20), 'Tag1', 19, 7,
    datetime(2020-07-04 13:50), 'Tag1', 51, 7,
    datetime(2020-07-04 14:10), 'Tag1', 39, 8,
    datetime(2020-07-04 14:20), 'Tag1', 37, 11,
]
| order by tag asc, timestamp asc, status asc
| extend Id = toint(prev(status) == 11)
| extend Id = 1 + row_cumsum(Id)
```

-->

```
| timestamp                   | tag  | value   | status | Id |
|-----------------------------|------|---------|--------|----|
| 2020-07-04 12:00:00.0000000 | Tag1 | 15.2391 | 2      | 1  |
| 2020-07-04 12:02:00.0000000 | Tag1 | 13.452  | 2      | 1  |
| 2020-07-04 12:04:00.0000000 | Tag1 | 17.239  | 4      | 1  |
| 2020-07-04 12:15:00.0000000 | Tag1 | 21.891  | 4      | 1  |
| 2020-07-04 12:17:00.0000000 | Tag1 | 18.9    | 11     | 1  |
| 2020-07-04 12:30:00.0000000 | Tag1 | 12      | 2      | 2  |
| 2020-07-04 12:32:00.0000000 | Tag1 | 15      | 2      | 2  |
| 2020-07-04 12:33:00.0000000 | Tag1 | 9       | 2      | 2  |
| 2020-07-04 12:45:00.0000000 | Tag1 | 17.5    | 4      | 2  |
| 2020-07-04 12:48:00.0000000 | Tag1 | 42      | 11     | 2  |
| 2020-07-04 13:12:00.0000000 | Tag1 | 22      | 2      | 3  |
| 2020-07-04 13:20:00.0000000 | Tag1 | 19      | 7      | 3  |
| 2020-07-04 13:50:00.0000000 | Tag1 | 51      | 7      | 3  |
| 2020-07-04 14:10:00.0000000 | Tag1 | 39      | 8      | 3  |
| 2020-07-04 14:20:00.0000000 | Tag1 | 37      | 11     | 3  |
```

Comment: Thanks Yoni, you put me on the right track, it only goes wrong when status 11 is recorded 2 times in a row, but I'm working on it.